problemas con SQL Server al actualizar a window 11
Al momento de actualizar de windows 10 a windows 11, no es posible levantar la instancia de SQL Server. Este problema no es la primera vez que me pasa, la vez anterior tuve que volver a la versión anterior de windows pero esta vez necesito mantener ambos. Probé también generando una nueva instancia pero tampoco es posible levantarlo desde la consola de servicios. He buscado casos similares en internet pero nada al respecto.
El mensaje que arroja el sistema al tratar de levantarlo es un error 1067


Has revisado el log de windows (event viewer)? qué errores reporta el servidor al caer?

finalmente Aquí pillé la solución. (aunque lamentablemente tuve que perder mis instancias anteriores)

Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Esos errores están asociados al inicio de la instancia de SQLServer. Las causas más habituales (según la documentación de Microsoft) son estas:

Problemas que afectan a la cuenta configurada para ejecutar el
servicio SQL Server
Bases de datos del sistema inaccesibles
Dependencias que faltan
Configuración incorrecta del servicio SQL
Server Problemas que afectan a la configuración del certificado

Revisa esa documentación y el "Visor de Eventos" de Windows como ya te han comentado.

Aqui Explican como resolver el mismo problema que estás teniendo.
Espero que te pueda servir

Muestra siempre un resumen, en la respuesta, del contenido del enlace que has agregado. Si el sitio que enlazaste cae más adelante, parte fundamental de la respuesta se perderá. Lee [answer].
